# How to combine a dataframe containing previous values ​with data frames containing current values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with matching indexes and columns. (30 columns).

index: **time and day**.

first dataframe:

```
time    day       200-approve-packages   200-delivered-packages     ...
10.15   sunday    158                    112                        
10:30   sunday    200                    110                        
10:45   sunday    158                    145                        
11:00   sunday    180                    170                        
...
```

and second:

```
time    day      200-approve-packages   200-delivered-packages     ...
10.15   sunday   198                    117
10:30   sunday   400                    200
10:45   sunday   154                    178
11:00   sunday   100                    200
...
```

the output should be like this:

```
time    day      200-approve-packages   previous-200-approve-packages    200-delivered-packages   previous-200-delivered-packages
10.15   sunday   198                    158                              117                      112
10:30   sunday   400                    200                              200                      110
10:45   sunday   154                    158                              178                      145
11:00   sunday   100                    180                              200                      170
...
```

the first data frame contains **previous** values ​​and the second data frame contains **current** values. is there a way to keep them understandably in a single data frame?

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`. This performs an outer join using the default index.

Comment: @Tristan I tried this but exactly what I want is for each column to be side by side with the "previous value column". it's easier to understand that way.

Comment: Then just reindex the columns afterwards.

Comment: @Tristan I tried some things, but I guess I didn't make it. can you explain a little more detail? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below lines if order of records is sme

```
 import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('main.xlsx')
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_excel('main2.xlsx')

df2['200-Previous-approve-packages']=df1['200-approve-packages']
df2['200-Previousdelivered-packages']=df1['200-delivered-packages']
df2.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)

# in case you need to rename columns below commented code can be used

#df1.rename(columns = {'200-approve-packages':'200-Previous-approve-packages','200-delivered-packages':'200-Previousdelivered-packages'}, inplace = True)
```

Below is data screenshot for refence

[image]